# Amazon Web Services Price History?

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

Is there a site that offers price history for various Amazon Web Services such as EC2, Cloudfront, etc?  Something like on 1/1/2009 a small on demand ec2 instance in the US East region cost $x.xxxx, on 1/1/2010 it cost $x.xxxx.

I would like to be able to forecast that if something like a small on demand EC2 instance costs $0.085 per hour today that it will likely half in cost to $0.043 per hour a year from now.  Similarly if I have 10GB of files in S3 storage how will the cost be affected over a similar span of time?  I can only imagine, that like all technology, the cost will go down.

I cannot seem to find any pricing information aside from this site which lists only the fluctuating cost of spot instances.

http://thecloudmarket.com/stats#/spot_prices

And this statement made by Amazon on 8/20/2009 claiming that reserved instance pricing had been reduced by 30%.

http://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2009/08/20/New-Lower-Prices-for-Amazon-EC2-Reserved-Instances/

Any suggestions?

Comment: There hasn't really been a need for anyone to make such a site since prices have only changed a couple times in the many years EC2 has been around. Less than once every other year! The CPU-hour price of a small instance has only changed once in the past 5 years -- from its original $0.10 to $0.085.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For anyone else looking for this, entering the following phrase in Google should be helpful for changes up through around 2014:

[site:aws.typepad.com pricing s3](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Aaws.typepad.com+pricing+s3)

For more recent changes,

[site:aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/ pricing s3](https://www.google.ca/search?q=site%3Aaws.amazon.com%2Fblogs%2Faws%2F+pricing+s3&oq=site%3Aaws.amazon.com%2Fblogs%2Faws%2F+pricing+s3)

This searches the AWS blog for `pricing s3` which brings up most of their previous price change announcements.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use the "Price Reduction" tag on the AWS Blog : http://aws.typepad.com/aws/price-reduction/

Answer (score 0):

You could always go through archive.org and check the prices on different dates. They have the prices going back to the beta [here.](http://wayback.archive.org/web/%2a/aws.amazon.com/ec2/#pricing)

Comment: This is helpful.  Unfortunately, it breaks down after Amazon started using Ajax to load their pricing after page load, starting with the June 2011 wayback entry.

Answer (score 0):

This site offers EC2 spot price histories accessible via an API:

http://ec2-spot-prices.ai-mmo-games.de/

I hope this helps.